# Getting a print line to only print once and printing the line number of a file

Tags: java, hashset, line-numbers

How do I keep "No Duplicates Found" print line from repeating instead of only getting it at the end and how do I print the line number of a file that I read into my program?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class b{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception{
        Scanner infile = new Scanner( new File( args[0] ) );
        HashSet<String> h = new HashSet<String>();

        while(infile.hasNext()){
            String word = infile.next();
            if(h.contains(word)){
                System.out.println("DUPLICATE at line" + " " +  );
            }else if(!h.contains(word)){
                System.out.println("No Duplicate Found");
            }else{
                h.add(word);
            }   
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly, this should help to resolve all problems with incorrectly nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class b{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception{
        Scanner infile = new Scanner( new File( args[0] ) );
        HashSet<String> h = new HashSet<String>();
        boolean noDuplicateFound;
        lineCount = 0;

        while(infile.hasNextLine()){
            lineCount++
            String word = infile.next();
            h.add(word);
            if(h.contains(word)){
                System.out.println("DUPLICATE at line: " + lineCount);
            }else if(!h.contains(word)){
                noDuplicateFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(noDuplicateFound)
            System.out.println("No Duplicate Found");
    }   
}
```

Comment: When I run this on my file, it tells me No Duplicate Found when I know there is a duplicate

Comment: a typo by me most likely. change if(duplicateFound) to if(noDuplicateFound)

Comment: I didn't realise but your whole logic is wrong. Let me fix it for you.

Comment: I get it to only print No Duplicate Found once with your help, but now it isn't identifying the duplicate